# Change PostgreSQL log directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

How can I change the log directory from PostgreSQL 12? I need to change the default /var/log/ location to point to another disk location.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DIRECTORY

Comment: The default depends on what the packager who packaged your distribution decided to do.   So, how did you install PostgreSQL?  (If you build from source, the default is not /var/log).

Answer (score 0):

Edit `postgresql.conf`, set `logging_collector = on` (if it isn't already set that way) and change `log_directory` appropriately.

Then restart PostgreSQL (if you didn't change `logging_collector`, then a reload is enough).

Comment: I've tried this but the location in log_directory as default is logs. and when I change it points to a different location and postgre goes down

Comment: Per the comment on your question, how did you install Postgres and on what OS version? My guess is you are fighting the packagers script that sets the logging directory.